# Working with images in servlets

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

I am quite familiar with HTML, CSS, Adobe Flash and JavaScript. I would make my own graphics and build a website myself.

But when programming in Java with servlets it seems I only have two choices to display a graphic:

1. use an image encoder (gif encoder) and print that out.
2. or print out a supported image format (jpeg i think is supported).

So my questions are

1. How do I manipulate the image with HTML/CSS/JavaScript? For example, Say I want to put a border on an image with padding etc?
2. How do I display Adobe Flash content? Is that possible at all?
3. Is there other Java Server Side technologies that can do it? Is JSP or JSF better for this than Servlets?

Thanks
Aubrey.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use Java, but if I did, I'd convert the input (jpeg, png, bmp, gif) into a `BufferedImage`, manipulate that, then write out the result in the desired image format.

Answer (score 0):

Java jsp/servlets/jsf and many other framworks using the java language all support every web content available (and not only jpegs....).

Now for your question 1, there are tones of ways to achieve that, I would not go in detail. If you have a specific questions i would be happy to answer it.

Flash content is also supported. I would not go in any detail also in this. There are plenty of questions answering your question on SO.

Concluding I would like to stress that eventually, which ever technology you use, every framework JUST outputs html code on the user browser. So the framework is not important as much as the experience and learning curve you want to invest with it.